# Injecting a variable into pom.xml from Jenkinsfile

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to configure SCM for my maven release plugin. However, the issue is: the pom.xml in my archetype, I dont want to hardcode a single scm variable but rather a parametrized version. In my jenkinsfile, we have a proprietary tool that fills the scm url, so I want to substitute that url into my pom.xml once I setup the project from my archetype. See code snippet below.

```
  <developerConnection>scm:git:${myVariable}</developerConnection>
```

In my Jenkinsfile, I pull out this value like this (this works correctly):

```
node {
    stage 'Checkout'
    checkout scm
    def myVariable= sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git config remote.origin.url').trim()
```

So, to recap, I want to know how the value from Jenkins can get substituted into the pom.xml?

Right now, I am getting this error:

```
[INFO] fetch url: ${myVariable}
[INFO] push url: ${myVariable}
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.755 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-17T16:21:00+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/784M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project newSeedService: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command. JGit checkin failure! ${myVariable}: not found. -> [Help 1]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you want to isolate these properties from the project POM, you can use properties file, you will have to use Properties Maven plugin, and run it's read-project-properties goal in the initialize phase of the Maven lifecycle. The example from the plugin page is reproduced here:

```
<project>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <files>
            <file>etc/config/dev.properties</file>
          </files>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```